# Looking for ZLIB library in JS or Pure Java that can work with GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, zlib

I am developing with GWT and need to decomrpess some data.
I can't find any good library in JS or in Java that would compile with GWT.

Comment: Where are you loading your data from? If you're loading it _via_ HTTP, your browser should handle the decompression for you (provided the server sends the appropriate [`Content-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) header)

Comment: No, this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search turns up [this](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) implementation of zlib in pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jsmol/test2.htm) suggests that [JSmol](http://jsmol.sourceforge.net/) is using [JZlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) in javascript by using [Java2Script](http://j2s.sourceforge.net/).